# C99, "Despite the name, a non-directive is a preprocessing directive."

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c99

What does the quoted footnote in the title mean? It's a footnote attached to 6.10.3p11

> If there are sequences of preprocessing tokens within the list of arguments that would otherwise act as preprocessing directives,<sup>147)</sup> the behavior is undefined.

I checked up and found

> A preprocessing directive consists of a sequence of preprocessing tokens that begins with a # preprocessing token that ...

and I didn't find the non-terminal `non-directive` matching that syntax. It can, but doesn't have to, start with a `#` preprocessing token. So wouldn't we have to say the following?

> "Despite the name, a preprocessing directive is a non-directive."

Also, what is the purpose of that footnote?

Comment: In case this helps anyone (it certainly didn't help me), it was added in TC2.

Comment: Perhaps the footnote should have said "Despite the name, a non-directive *can be* a preprocessing directive".  I still don't know the intent behind/rationale for the footnote.

Comment: A *non-directive* is not simply anything that's not a directive. A *non-directive* is anything on a line starting with `#` that doesn't start with any of the directive names given in the syntax. Perhaps something like *unrecognized-directive* would have been a better name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_250.htm It is to clarify that

```
#define nothing(x) // Nothing    /* Case 1 */
nothing (
#nonstandard
)
```

is UB.

Answer (score 4):

My copy of C99 doesn't have that footnote (it's the original - do you have one with TR corrections applied?) but I think the idea is that if you have

```
# non-directive
```

inside a macro argument list, that's still undefined behavior.

It would have been better to make the <*non-directive*> production include the `#`, I think, it would simplify 6.10p3,4 as well as removing this confusion.

Comment: The footnote was added in TC2.

Comment: Thanks, I think you explained it nicely.